# Prolog callable expected found integer error

Tags: prolog

I have a 2x2 axis (20 by 15). In there, I want to compute the location of the centers of two circles.  computeShapeBelow/2 looks for possible centers of two circles given that the first is below the second circle and of course the circles' edges should be within my X-Y axes 20 by 15 limits. I get the error: `callable' expected, found 2' (an integer)`. The error and the query below shows the expected circle structure input `[[circle, id], Radius, [X, Y]].` I have looked at some answers here on StackOverflow but the solutions or why this error is raised is not quite clear. Additionally, the SWIPL documentation is too brief on the uses of callable/1, call/1, and call/2.

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

computeShapeBelow(Shape1,Shape2,Xcord1,Ycord1,Xcord2,Ycord2) :- 
   nth0(2,Shape1,Location1), nth0(2,Shape2,Location2),
   nth0(1,Shape1,Dim1), nth0(1,Shape2,Dim2),
   nth0(0,Location1,Xcord1), nth0(0,Location2,Xcord2),
   nth0(1,Location1,Ycord1), nth0(1,Location2,Ycord2),
   Xcord1 in 0..20, Xcord2 in 0..20, 
   Ycord1 in 0..15, Ycord2 in 0..15,
   Ycord2 #> Ycord1+Dim1, Dim2.

?- computeShapeBelow([[circle1,1],4,[X1,Y1]],[[circle,2],2,[X2,Y2]], X1, Y1, X2,Y2).
ERROR: Type error: `callable' expected, found `2' (an integer)
ERROR: In:
ERROR:    [8] computeShapeBelow([[circle1|...],4|...],[[circle|...],2|...])
ERROR:    [7] <user>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably a typo, you're calling `Dim2` here

> ...,Ycord2 #> Ycord1+Dim1,Dim2.

But, as a general style note, beware of mixing CLP(FD) constructs with traditional Prolog ones, like nth0/3. In my experience, when it comes to debug a problem, CLP(FD) requires a *very* different mindset, since execution should be delayed until the instantiation state of variables gets known, and 'touching' the variables (for instance, collecting them with findall/3) could lead to unexpected results.

If your problem doesn't require CLP(FD), but brute force is sufficient, it's probably easier to use between/3 instead of `VAR in Low..High`, for instance

```
Xcord1 in 0..20,
```

could be

```
between(0,20,Xcord1),
```